# Designing a class diagram for a domain model

Tags: uml, domain-driven-design, class-diagram

First, don't think i'm trying to get the job done by someone else, but i'm trying to design a class diagram for a domain model and something I do is probably wrong because I'm stuck, so I just want to get hints about what i'm not doing correctly to continue...

For example, the user needs to search products by categories from a product list. Each category may have subcategories which may have subcategories, etc.

The first diagram I made was this (simplified):
[image]

The user also needs to get a tree list of categories **which have at least one product**.
For example, if this is **all** the categories tree:

- Music instruments

  - Wind
  - String

    - Guitars
    - Violins
  - Percussion
- Books

  - Comics
  - Fiction
  - Romance

I can't return a tree of Category **which have at least one product** because I would also get all subCategories, but not each sub category has a product associated to it.

I also can't remove items from the Category.subCategories collection to keep only items which have associated products because it would alter the Category entity, which may be shared elsewhere, this is not what I want.

I thought of doing a copy, but than I would get 2 different instances of the same entity in the same context, isn't it a bad thing ?

So I redesigned to this:
[image]

Now I don't get a collection of child categories I don't want with each Category, I only know about its parent category, which is ok.

However, this creates a tree of categories which is navigable only from the bottom to the top, it makes no sense for the client of ProductList who will always need a top -> bottom navigation of categories.

As a solution I think of the diagram below, but i'm not sure it is very good because it kinda dupplicates things, also the CategoryTreeItem does not seems very meaningful in the domain language.
[image]

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Actually the self-reference in category creates a tree.

Comment: @ThomasKilian I updated the statement after the second diagram about having no tree. In fact there is a tree but the client of ProductList needs always a top->bottom navigable tree, but in this case the tree is navigable only from bottom to top

Comment: The first variant is navigable both directions. The one via the collection/composition and vice versa via the parent.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on the purpose of the diagram. Do you apply a certain software development method that defines the purpose of this diagram in a certain context and the intended readers audience?

Because you talk about a 'domain model', I guess your goal is to provide a kind of conceptual model, i.e. a model of the concepts needed to communicate the application's functionality to end users, testers etc. In that case, the first and the second diagram are both valid, but without the operations (FilterByCategory and GetCategories), because these are not relevant for that audience. The fact that the GUI only displays a subset of the full category tree is usually not expressed in a UML diagram, but in plain text.

On the other hand, if your intention is to provide a technical design for developers, then the third diagram is valid. The developers probably need a class to persist categories in the database ('Category') and a separate class to supply categories to the GUI ('CategoryTreeItem'). You are right that this distinction is not meaningful in the domain language, but in a technical design, it is common to have such additional classes. Please check with the developers if your model is compatible with the programming language and libraries/frameworks they use.

One final remark:
In the first diagram, you specified multiplicity=1 on the parent side. This would mean that *every* Category has a parent, which is obviously not true. The second diagram has the correct multiplicity: 0..1. The third diagram has an incorrect multiplicity=1 on the composition of CategoryTreeItem.

Comment: About the tree of categories for the second diagram, my statement was not exact, indeed they are arranged in a tree, but the tree is only navigable from the bottom to the top, which makes no sense for the client, it needs a tree navigable from top categories to subcategories.

Comment: +1 for having pointed out the multiplicity problem.

In the second paragraph, you mean you would only return a flat category to the client and let it display it in a tree, but it is only moving the problem, since the client will always need a top->down tree, it seems it should be returned this way. It also seems relatively complex to reverse a down->top tree into a top->down

Comment: I have added a paragraph about navigating the associations in both directions.

Comment: But this tree contains all subcategories, not only those with products associated

Comment: I see you're more or less arguing along the same lines as me. Looks to me as a trees/forest problem ;-)

Comment: @Jonathan, you are right. I have completely rewritten my answer.

Comment: @www.admiraalit.nl This diagram is primarily for domain experts and users but it is also useful for developpers.
The ProductList methods shown here were only provided as an example and the final implementation may be a little different, but when i'm modeling I want to validate by writing few lines of code to see if it solve correctly the typical scenarios. And that's where I was stuck trying to design the classes so that I could return a top->down tree of categories having products associated to.

Comment: Well I guess my second diagram is better, I'll just let the developper handle how will be structured the collection of categories returned by the ProductList.

Comment: In that case, personally, I would prefer the first diagram, because users tend to speak about categories having zero or more subcategories rather than about categories having an optional parent category.
Anyway, if you are satisfied with my answer as it is now, please mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 3):

This is rather an algorithmic question than a model question. Your first approach is totally ok, unless you were silent about constraints. So you can assign a category or a sub-category to any product. If you assign a sub-category, this means as per this model, the product will also have the parent category. To make it clear I would attach a constraint that tells that a product needs to be assigned to the most finest know category grain. E.g. the guitar products would be assigned to the `Guitar` category. As more strange instrument like the Stick would get the `Strings` category (which not would mean its a guitar *and* a violin but just in the higher category.

Now when you will implement `Category` you might think of a method to return a collection of `assignedInstruments()` which for `Guitar` would return `Fender`, `Alhambra`, etc. You might augment this `assignedInstruments(levelUp:BOOL)` to get also those instruments of the category above.

Generally you must be clear about what the category assignment basically means. If you change the assignment the product will end up in another list.

Comment: +1 for the constraint of a product need to be attached to the most finest known category, this is true.

But not sure about the second part, you are talking about how to retreive other categories from one category, but I need to retreive categories, in a top->down tree, from all the products in the ProductList, not starting from a specific category.

Comment: The product is assigned a category. And the category (as per first design) has a composition of sub-categories. So you are open in all directions. Not seeing the forest in front of the trees?

Comment: Maybe not... If I return a collection of Category and each category have a collection of all its subcategories, I can't return only categories having at least one product associated...
For example there is a product with String category and another with Guitar category, if I GetCategories returns the String category, it also return all String's subcategories, not only Guitar...

Comment: On the first level your CAT collection is on *one* level. The deeper levels are not returned directly. You can retrieve them from the top level by recursing, though.

Comment: Well the problem is that I need to return to the client a tree of categories which is navigable from top to bottom AND contains only categories+subcategories that have at least one product associated to it, not all subcategories.
If I return a collection of top categories, the client will navigate recursively and see all subcategories instead of only those with products.

Comment: This is just  a coding issue - how you implement what is returned. Just design methods that will deliver what you need (honestly I'll not try to dive into those details). Once they are specified and added as class methods you are done. Leave it to the coders to implement it.

Answer (score 0):

From my perspective your design is overly complex.

Crafting a domain model around querying needs is usually the wrong approach. Domain models are most useful to express domain behaviors. In other words, to process commands and protect invariants within the correct boundaries.

If your `Product` Aggregate Root (AR) references a `Category` AR by id and this relationship is stored in a relationnal DB then you can easily fulfill any of the mentionned querying use cases with a simple DB query. You'd start by gathering a flat representation of the tree which could then be used to construct an in-memory tree.

These queries could be exposed through a `ProductQueryService` that is part of the application layer, not the domain as those aren't used to enforce domain rules or invariants: I assumed they are used to fullfil reporting or UI display needs. It is there you could have a concept such as `ProductCategoryTreeItemDTO` for the in-memory representation.

You are also using the wrong terms according to DDD tactical patterns in your diagrams which is very misleading. An AR is an Entity, but an Entity is not necessarily an AR. The Entity term is mostly used to refer to a concept that is uniquely identified within the boundary of it's AR only, but not globally.

Comment: So if I only query a simple list of objects and don't do much things with it besides displaying, you say I shouldn't use the domain model for that ? 
Yes it makes sense for simple queries, but in my case, there are some (moderately complex) business rules to decide which products will be included in the list, moving these rules in the db query does not seem a good idea to me don't you think ?

Comment: For the DDD terms, I don't see where i'm wrong ? the 2 entities are also their own AR, the ProductList is a value object since 2 lists with the same products are considered the same. Product will have other classes associated later to eventually create an aggregate (for example prices, parts, etc.)
What may be confusing in the design I shown is that I didn't include the entity which has the responsability to generate the product list. There is a PointOfSale entity which will build different product lists depending on some context.

Comment: @Jonathan Query predicates are often not really considered as domain rules, but when you think they are then you can try to keep these inside the domain. For instance, nothing would prevent you from having a dedicated domain service that encapsulate the logic to determine which products have to be included. The query service could then use that domain service to constrain the query, but the entire query doesn't have to be in the domain. E.g. the domain service may return a `List<ProductId>` of the ones that have to be included.

Comment: @Jonathan My point was just that you should be labeling ARs as Aggregate Root in your diagram rather than Entity, because it's unclear if these entities are also the root of their own AR. For instance, I could think that Category is actually an entity under the Product AR by looking at the diagram.

Comment: Your point of separating the querying service from the domain is interesting. But I always thought all accesses to persisted objects should be done through domain objects (loaded through repositories) and client code is dealing with the domain objects, not the data only.

Comment: @Jonathan When you process commands, you load aggregates from repositories, invoke commands on the ARs and persist the changes through repositories. However, when you are only querying data you do not have to go through aggregates, because there's no transactional boundary and invariants to enforce. Bypassing the domain model for queries is often desired to avoid polluting the domain model with purely display or reporting concepts.

Comment: @Jonathan If I were you I'd read about CQRS. You do not have to apply full fledge CQRS, but understanding the ideas and motivations behind it is very helpful nevertheless.